# access web based mysql database/Server from Windows .net Application

Tags: .net, mysql, web

I want to connect database of mySql server which i kept on my website.
I tried connecting it by using info provided to make dynamics website.
e.g. server for MySQL of my web is;

> examplebiz1.ipagemysql.com;Uid='user';Pwd='pass'

but i'm getting below exception;
**

> Unable to connect to any of the Specified MYSQL Host.

**

Is it possible? if yes then i'd like to know how?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the connection in the web.config file, don't know how you use it, but the complete sentence would be

```
 <configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataConnectionString" connectionString="server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;User Id=XXX;password=XXXX;Persist Security Info=True;database=XXXXX" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
 </configuration
```

This should solve it if you use web.config as storage for configurations of your system

Edit: Remembering that you need to have a MySql connector dll at you machine for tests and in the bin folder of you website